# warning while trying to access the timeago library's format function

Tags: reactjs, npm, timeago

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/timeago.js/esm/format.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'C:\Users\SMDP-\Desktop\media-social\client\node_modules\timeago.js\src\format.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\SMDP-\Desktop\media-social\client\node_modules\timeago.js\src\format.ts'

WARNING in ./node_modules/timeago.js/esm/index.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'C:\Users\SMDP-\Desktop\media-social\client\node_modules\timeago.js\src\index.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\SMDP-\Desktop\media-social\client\node_modules\timeago.js\src\index.ts'
WARNING in ./node_modules/timeago.js/esm/lang/en_US.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'C:\Users\SMDP-\Desktop\media-social\client\node_modules\timeago.js\src\lang\en_US.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\SMDP-\Desktop\media-social\client\node_modules\timeago.js\src\lang\en_US.ts'

WARNING in ./node_modules/timeago.js/esm/lang/zh_CN.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'C:\Users\SMDP-\Desktop\media-social\client\node_modules\timeago.js\src\lang\zh_CN.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\SMDP-\Desktop\media-social\client\node_modules\timeago.js\src\lang\zh_CN.ts'

WARNING in ./node_modules/timeago.js/esm/realtime.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'C:\Users\SMDP-\Desktop\media-social\client\node_modules\timeago.js\src\realtime.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\SMDP-\Desktop\media-social\client\node_modules\timeago.js\src\realtime.ts'

WARNING in ./node_modules/timeago.js/esm/register.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'C:\Users\SMDP-\Desktop\media-social\client\node_modules\timeago.js\src\register.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\SMDP-\Desktop\media-social\client\node_modules\timeago.js\src\register.ts'

WARNING in ./node_modules/timeago.js/esm/utils/date.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'C:\Users\SMDP-\Desktop\media-social\client\node_modules\timeago.js\src\utils\date.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\SMDP-\Desktop\media-social\client\node_modules\timeago.js\src\utils\date.ts'

WARNING in ./node_modules/timeago.js/esm/utils/dom.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'C:\Users\SMDP-\Desktop\media-social\client\node_modules\timeago.js\src\utils\dom.ts' file: 
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\SMDP-\Desktop\media-social\client\node_modules\timeago.js\src\utils\dom.ts'
```

i'm new to react and trying to debug this issue is becoming a problem .
any help ?

to resolve this warning
i tried adding this below line to package .json file but didn't work .
warnings still remain.

```
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false
```

Comment: How did you install `timeago`?  It looks to me like it was not installed correctly.  You're missing some of the files.

Comment: @TimRoberts i just did npm install timeago.js

Comment: But not `npm install react-timeago`?

Comment: i got it thanks tho....

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Came here with the same issue. The solution, as pointed out by @TimRoberts, is to use `react-timeago` instead of `timeago.js`.  
That should be the answer of this question. I'll let @TimRoberts post it.

Answer (score 0):

To use timeago with react, you need

```
npm install react-timeago
```

not the "plain" timeago package.

Comment: It worked thanks